# In Unix using shell to rename multiple files

Tags: shell

There are many files and names like `*.txt`; how can I rename all the files to `*YYYYMMDD.txt`
with a shell script.

Comment: You want to add example? It isn't clear from your question what you want to do.

Comment: Look up the `rename` command (different from the `rename()` function in standard C), and the `prename` command.  And probably a lot of other questions on SO.

Comment: @freespace: for late response, There are many files like a.txt,b.txt,c.txt... , Now i will rename all the file to aYYYYMMDD.txt,bYYYYMMDD.txt,cYYYYMMDD.txt.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Thank your reply, i'm a fresher in UNIX shell, so i ask the inital problem, thanks very much!

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a move operation and could be quite dangerous if done wrong:

Run this first to make sure the script generates correct command

```
ls *.txt | while read FILE; do echo mv "$FILE" "${FILE/.txt/`date +%Y%m%d.txt`}"; done
```

Then when you are sure

```
ls *.txt | while read FILE; do mv "$FILE" "${FILE/.txt/`date +%Y%m%d.txt`}"; done
```

Comment: Also, it makes sense to calculate the date just once, before the loop.

Comment: @user1244240, I doubt that. Can you explain why you think ls is required?

Comment: @glenn jackman: for late response, There are many files like a.txt,b.txt,c.txt... , Now i will rename all the file to aYYYYMMDD.txt,bYYYYMMDD.txt,cYYYYMMDD.txt.